# Very poor SMB3 (and SMB2) performance between Linux SMB client and Samba 4 Server

Tags: samba

I work in a mainly Windows client environment, but we use Samba 4.3.10 as the file server (on RHEL 6.x). Windows 10 clients are able to negotiate and use SMB3 just fine, and Windows 7 machines are happy on SMB2.x

However, I have a CentOS7 Linux client that I'm also connecting to the Samba file server.  SMB1 works OK, and the default file manager only ever wants to use that, but won't negotiate SMB2 or SMB3.  I've tried a handful of other file managers from the CentOS yum repo and all of them select SMB1, nothing better.  If I block SMB1 by having `min protocol=SMB2` in my `smb.conf` on the server, then the Linux client just doesn't connect at all.

I know the Linux kernel definitely supports SMB3, and I can mount the share with SMB3 using a command like:

```
sudo mount -t cifs "//{server}/{share}" -o username={username},\
domain={domain},\vers=3\.0 /mnt/{mountdir}
```

But the performance is awful!  I can see the files and permissions are fine, but any file-write operation (eg, 'touch file') takes up to 30 seconds to complete every time, and it's not unusable. It's the same behaviour with SMB2.x

I'd really like to adopt SMB3 (or 2.x) and not have to leave this system on the old (legacy?) SMB1.

I repeated the setup on a second Linux system and the behaviour is the same.

Any ideas why it's not working properly?

Thanks

mrc

Comment: Why escaping the `\vers` and `\.0` ?  Please also paste the /proc/mounts entry once it's been mounted.  And versions of the samba rpm on the client and server.

Comment: The escaping is being done as the examples I picked up from the web were done like that, and that syntax works so I didn't change it.

Comment: The command line I last tried was actually more like this:  'sudo mount -t cifs "//{server}/{share}" --verbose -o username={username},domain={domain},\vers=3\.0,rw,uid=1000,sec=ntlmssp,cache=none,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755 /mnt/{mountdir}' and I've tried many variations with same results or worse.

Comment: The /proc/mounts line says: '//{server}/{share} /mnt/{mountdir} cifs rw,relatime,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmssp,cache=none,username={username},domain={domain},uid=1000,forceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,serverino,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,actimeo=1 0 0'

Comment: It's not the usual repo version of Samba but a variant: "Version 4.3.10-ArcaPix-SerNet-RedHat-26.arcapix.el6"

Comment: humor me, try adding `strict allocate = yes` into your server's smb.conf and then restart samba there.....

Comment: I am also observing a very high latency with the vers=3.0 mount option. Throughput is ok, but also parallel access is a mess. E.g. when copying a file, i have to wait forever for a stat or list to complete. Does this match your observation? see also: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91621

Comment: I found that it always worked fine if i tried it against a Windows 2012R2 server; and against a SAMBA server, using a newer SMB client kernel and later CIFSutils produced better results, but still not great.